# HTTP request is not working, setting Authorization using setRequestProperty method

Tags: java, rest, httpurlconnection

I am trying to make a get request in Java. However, when I run this code,

```
URL urlForGetRequest = new URL("my_url");   
String readLine = null;
HttpURLConnection conection = (HttpURLConnection) urlForGetRequest.openConnection();
conection.setRequestMethod("GET");

String username = "user";
String password = "pass";

String basicAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username+":"+password).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
System.out.println(basicAuth);

conection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+basicAuth);

int responseCode = conection.getResponseCode();

System.out.println(responseCode);
```

It always returns a 403. I can type the url into the address bar and it returns what I need it to. Similarly, the credentials are correct. Am I missing a setRequestProperty beyond Authorization?

Comment: I guess the `urlForGetRequest` for your site and url for login are different. When you click the login button, you request some url, that's should be your urlForGetRequest.

Comment: Do I make a query twice, then? How do I log in with one url then request data from another?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the `urlForGetRequest` for your site and url for login are different. When you open a site, it's one url, and when you click the login button, you request another url, that's should be your `urlForGetRequest`.

Just try to login by correct hardcoded url for a start. And use POST method. And then you can either hardcode this url in your code or parse HTML response with jsoup, selenium maybe. I didn't solve such problems honestly. If you can control the code of this site, you can integrate some other auth options (0Auth, tokens) I'm not savvy with that, maybe someone can help you with it, it's another topic